# A Non-Uniformly Spaced Display of \ldots. is Produced When Using Fontspec

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, best-practices, ellipsis

Consider the following code which I compile with `Lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
Some words\ldots. % ellipsis and period without fontspec 
%Some words\ldots. % ellipsis and period with fontspec 
\end{document}
```

which nicely produces

[image]

However, when I call in the `fontspec` package and run the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
%Some words\ldots. % ellipsis and period without fontspec 
Some words\ldots. % ellipsis and period with fontspec 
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

QUESTION: How may I, using `fontspec`, produce `\ldots.` as nicely as when not using the package and compiling with `lualatex`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, `\ldots` used in text mode will eventually expand to `\textellipsis`.

Then, `\textellipsis` will result in different output with non-unicode engines like pdfTeX and unicode engines like XeTeX and LuaTeX.

With non-unicode engines, either font encoding `T1` and `OT1` will use the default definition, which will typeset three loosely spaced dots.

```tex
% latex.ltx, line 7205:
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}{%
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font}
```

With unicode engines, by default font encoding `TU` is used, and in such encoding the `\textellipsis` will directly use the character `U+2026` in current font. And this character in the default Latin Modern Roman font is provided as three closely spaced dots.

A quick workaround would be to redefine `\textellipsis` under `TU` encoding to its default definition.

```tex
% compile with xelatex or lualatex
\documentclass{book}

% comment out this definition to see the default output
\DeclareTextCommand\textellipsis{TU}
  {\csname T1\string\textellipsis\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{n}
--\ldots-- % ellipsis in Computer Modern Roman

\usefont{TU}{lmr}{m}{n}
--\ldots-- % ellipsis in Latin Modern Roman
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am interested in this question. But when I run the above code both with `lualatex` and with `xelatex`, I get an error indicating that `! TeX capacity exceeded`. Do you know what may be causing this problem and how to avoid it?

Comment: @Garfunkel It works ok on overleaf.com, texlive2021. Perhaps your latex and/or luatex version is outdated?